# null is not an object evaluating 'route.component'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigator

I planed to implement react native project. Created  sample components , routings but i am having an issue "null is not an object evaluating 'route.component'"

[here is the error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMjrS.png)

Here is the Navigate.js file

```
import { BackAndroid } from 'react-native';

 let routes = null;

try {
   routes = require('../routes').default;
} catch (e) {
}

export default class Navigate {


static getInitialRoute = (path, customRoutes) => {
    if (customRoutes) {
        routes = customRoutes;
    }
    if (!routes) {
        console.warn(`[Navigate.getInitialRoute()] No routes found. Add routes to src/routes.js.`);
        return null;
    }
    if (path) {
        return {
            path,
            ...routes[path]
        }
    } else {
        let initial;
        for (const route in routes) {
            if (routes[route].initialRoute) {
                initial = {path: route, ...routes[route]};
                break;
            }
        }
        return initial || {
            path,
            ...routes[Object.keys(routes)[0]]
        }
    }
};

constructor(navigator) {
    this.navigator = navigator;
    this.savedInstanceStates = new Map();
    this.currentRoute = null;
    this.previousRoute = null;
    this.isChild = false;
    BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this._hardwareBackPress);
}


_getPathPrettyName = (path) => {
    path = path.split('.');
    if (path.length === 1) {
        path = path[0]
    } else {
        path = path[path.length - 1];
    }
    return path.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + path.slice(1);
};

/**
* Handle hardware back press
* @returns {boolean}
*/
_hardwareBackPress = () => {
    if (this.navigator.getCurrentRoutes()[0].path == Navigate.getInitialRoute().path) {
        BackAndroid.exitApp();
        return false;
    } else {
        if (!this.isChild) {
            route = Navigate.getInitialRoute();
            this.currentRoute = route;
            this.navigator.replace(route);
            return true;
        } else {
            this.back();
            return true;
        }
    }
};


_getRouteObject = (path) => {
    let obj = routes;
    const properties = path.replace(/\./g, '.children.').split('.');
    if (properties.length === 1) return obj[path];
    properties.forEach(function (key) {
        if (!obj || !hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
            obj = undefined;
            return;
        }
        obj = obj[key];
    });
    return obj;
};

// TODO
_saveInstanceState = (path, instanceState) => {
    if (instanceState) {
        this.savedInstanceStates.set(path, instanceState);
    }
};

// TODO
_recoverInstanceState = (path) => {
    const instanceState = this.savedInstanceStates.get(path);
    if (instanceState) {
        this.savedInstanceStates.delete(path);
    }
    return instanceState || null;
};

to = (path, title, props) => {
    if (!path) {
        console.warn(`[Navigate.to(undefined)] A route path is required to navigate to`);
    } else {
        const obj = this._getRouteObject(path);

        if (!obj || !obj.component) {
            console.warn(`[Navigate.to(${path})] No component exists at this path`);
        } else {
            this.isChild = path.split('.').length > 1;
            const route = {
                title: title ? title : (obj.title ? obj.title : path),
                path,
                component: obj.component,
                props
            };
            this.previousRoute = this.currentRoute;
            this.currentRoute = route;
            this.navigator.replace(route);
        }
    }
};

/**
* Go back to the parent of the current component
* @param title
* @param props
*/
back = (title, props) => {
    const current = this.navigator.getCurrentRoutes()[0].path;
    const path = current.substr(0, current.lastIndexOf('.'));
    const obj = this._getRouteObject(path);
    const savedInstance = this._recoverInstanceState(path); // TODO

    if (!obj) {
        console.warn(`[Navigate.back()] No component exists for the parent of ${current}`);
    } else {
        this.isChild = path.split('.').length > 1;
        const route = {
            // title: title ? title : (obj.title || this._getPathPrettyName(path)),
            title: title ? title : (this.previousRoute ? this.previousRoute.title : (obj.title || this._getPathPrettyName(path))),
            path,
            component: obj.component,
            props
        };

        this.currentRoute = route;
        this.navigator.replace(route);
    }
};


forward = (child, title, props, savedInstanceState) => {
    const current = this.navigator.getCurrentRoutes()[0].path;
    const currentObject = this._getRouteObject(current);

    if (!currentObject.children || !Object.keys(currentObject.children).length) {
        console.warn(`[Navigate.forward()] No child components exists for ${current}`);
    } else {
        this.isChild = true;
        if (child) {
            const obj = this._getRouteObject(`${current}.${child}`);
            if (!obj) {
                console.warn(`[Navigate.forward(${child})] Child component ${child} does not exist on ${current}`);
            } else {
                const route = {
                    title: title ? title : (obj.title || this._getPathPrettyName(`${current}.${child}`)),
                    path: `${current}.${child}`,
                    component: obj.component,
                    props
                };
                this.previousRoute = this.currentRoute;
                this.currentRoute = route;
                this.navigator.replace(route);
            }
        } else {
            const path = `${current}.${Object.keys(currentObject.children)[0]}`;
            const obj = this._getRouteObject(path);
            const route = {
                title: title ? title : (obj.title ? obj.title : this._getPathPrettyName(path)),
                path,
                component: obj.component,
                props
            };
            this.currentRoute = route;
            this.navigator.replace(route);
        }
    }
};

getRoutes = () => {
    return routes;
};

setRoutes = (newRoutes) => {
    // todo deep clone?
    routes = newRoutes;
};
```

};

Below is the routes.js file

```
export default {

Home: {
    initialRoute: true,

    title: 'Welcome',
    component: require('./scenes/Home').default,

    }
},

Profile: {
    title: 'Profile',
    component: require('./scenes/Profile').default
},

Updates: {

    title: 'Updates',
    component: require('./scenes/Updates').default
}
}
```

Comment: It says the error is in `renderScene` but you haven't provided that method...

Comment: Most likely the issue is you're not passing the correct object into the router. Can you provide the code you're using to actually push the navigation route?